# List-item starting in the middle of the box

Tags: html, css

I want to have a margin on the right and left side of the list-items hence why I created the "wrapper", can someone figure out why it starts somewhat on the center and not from left to right?

Here's a jsfiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/vd8rb51s/

```css
.add-remove-skills {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #d1d9de;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 287px;
  height: 394px
}
ul.edit-skills {
}
ul.edit-skills li {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  background: #000;
  margin-bottom: 15px
}
.skills-wrapper {
  width: 267px;
  margin: 0 auto
}
h3.manage-skills {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #d1d9de
}
input.add-skill {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 16px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  text-indent: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border: none;
  border-top: 2px solid #d1d9de
}
input.add-skill::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* WebKit browsers */
  color: #939fa7;
  font-weight: 500
}
input.add-skill:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
  color: #939fa7;
  font-weight: 500;
  opacity: 1
}
input.add-skill::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
  color: #939fa7;
  font-weight: 500;
  opacity: 1
}
input.add-skill:-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
  color: #939fa7;
  font-weight: 500
}
```

```html
<div class="add-remove-skills">
  <h3 class="manage-skills">Manage skills</h3>
  <div class="skills-wrapper">
    <ul class="edit-skills">
      <li>Skill number one</li>
      <li>Skill number two</li>
      <li>Skill number three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <input class="add-skill" placeholder="Add new skill here" type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most browsers add some `padding-left` to `ul` elements by default. Just remove it:

```css
.edit-skills {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```css
.add-remove-skills {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #d1d9de;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 287px;
  height: 394px;
}
ul.edit-skills {
  padding-left: 0;
}
ul.edit-skills li {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  background: #000;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.skills-wrapper {
  width: 267px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
h3.manage-skills {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px; 
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #d1d9de;
}
input.add-skill {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 16px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  text-indent: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border: none;
  border-top: 2px solid #d1d9de;
}
input.add-skill::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
  color:    #939fa7;
  font-weight: 500;
}
input.add-skill:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
  color:    #939fa7;
  font-weight: 500;
  opacity:  1;
}
input.add-skill::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
  color:    #939fa7;
  font-weight: 500;
  opacity:  1;
}
input.add-skill:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
  color:    #939fa7;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<div class="add-remove-skills">
  <h3 class="manage-skills">Manage skills</h3>
  <div class="skills-wrapper">
    <ul class="edit-skills">
      <li>Skill number one</li>
      <li>Skill number two</li>
      <li>Skill number three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="add-skill" placeholder="Add new skill here">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

unordered lists have a default indent/padding so that the bullets will not end up outside the list itself.

Ussually a CSS reset stylesheet would fix this kind of thing. It would contain something like this:
ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

or you can apply this in your case
ul.edit-skills { margin: 0; padding: 0; }